# Compare specific elements of an array to another array with Chai?

Tags: javascript, chai

I have two arrays that look like the following:

```
var arrayOne = [['Hello', 0, 'How'], ['World', 1, 'Are'], ['!', 9, 'You?']];
var arrayTwo = [['Hello', 7, 'How'], ['World', 6, 'Are'], ['!', 2, 'You?']];
```

I'm using Chai for assertions in my tests, and I'd like to use the BDD assertions to compare the first and third elements of the two arrays.

I know I could do something manually, like this:

```
var arrayOne = [['Hello', 0, 'How'], ['World', 1, 'Are'], ['!', 9, 'You?']];
var arrayTwo = [['Hello', 7, 'How'], ['World', 6, 'Are'], ['!', 2, 'You?']];

var importantBits = function(e) {
  return [e[0], e[2]];
};

var condensedOne = arrayOne.map(importantBits);
var condensedTwo = arrayTwo.map(importantBits);

condensedOne.should.deep.equal(condensedTwo);
```

However, I'd rather use something a bit more sophisticated if at all possible.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I'd do it:

```
const INDEXES = [ 0, 2 ];
INDEXES.forEach(function(idx) {
    condensedOne[idx].should.deep.equal(condensedTwo[idx]);
});
```

Hope I got the use of `should` right, I usually use `expect`.